# How do you activate multisampling in OpenGL ES on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, graphics, opengl-es

I'm experimenting w/ improving the "resolution" of an OpenGL ES based app.  Apple mentions [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/SupportingResolutionIndependence/SupportingResolutionIndependence.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH10-SW11) (developer.apple.com) that OpenGL ES in iOS 4 supports multisampling... and this can improve the graphics somewhat.  **How do you enable multisampling?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this help?

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/7552